# Whats the best way to accurately scroll to a DIV element with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page filled with DIVs and on the page load I need to have the browser automatically scroll to a pre-designated DIV.

I'm semi-successfully doing it like this

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#mydiv').position().top}, 'slow');
```

*The problem is that if the page contains images above #mydiv, the scroll will not be very accurate.  This is because as the images load, the browser pushes the content (including #mydiv) down (this is with Safari).*

**Solutions that don't work for me:**

1) **Give all the images a set width and height that way the browser knows ahead of time what their dimensions are** and won't push the content down as they load.  This doesn't work for me because the images are all from all over the internet and not hosted on my own server so I just don't know their dimensions ahead of time (these are user submitted photos)

2) **Run the page scroll after the page has completely loaded.**  This is also a non starter for me because it takes a few seconds for the images to load (many many images) and in that time the user will start to scroll his browser window and then it will suddenly jump to #mydiv.  It becomes very confusing and frustrating to the user.

What i'm hoping for are any ideas/pointers/code to other solutions?  Or am I .... out of luck for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: you can add #mydiv to the url of the page

Comment: example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760992/whats-the-best-way-to-accurately-scroll-to-a-div-element-with-javascript-jquery#copyright

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the animation yourself instead of letting `$.animate` do it. This way, you can continually check for the top of the div to scroll to and keep scrolling until you get there. As images load and the `position().top` changes, you'll know that you still have further to go. The problem here is that if you get there before all images are loaded, it would jump out again.

```
// in pseudocode
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
    // get the value of the position().top
    // check that value against the current scrollTop value
    // if not equal or greater than, scroll a little bit
    // else clear myInterval
}, 16); // play with the timer to get best effect
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot know the image sizes before they load.

The only logical solution is to add a loading time to your page and not display anything until the images are loaded. Check once the images are loaded using the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) library instead of `$(window).load(function()` (Since window load will wait for all assets, including footer javascript files) and then display the page and scroll to the required section.

Also, since the page is not displayed initially, the user also would not be able to start scrolling and get confused.